# How to create ONNXTensor for a single float value?

Tags: java, onnx, onnxruntime, onnx-coreml

I have the following java code :

```
try (OrtEnvironment env = OrtEnvironment.getEnvironment();
             OrtSession.SessionOptions opts = new OrtSession.SessionOptions()) {
            opts.setOptimizationLevel(OrtSession.SessionOptions.OptLevel.BASIC_OPT);

            try (OrtSession session = env.createSession("model.onnx", opts)) {
                OnnxTensor.createTensor(env, 10.0f);
            }
        }
```

I want to create an OnnxTensor of a float value. I am getting the below Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" ai.onnxruntime.OrtException: Cannot convert class java.lang.Float to an OnnxTensor.
    at ai.onnxruntime.TensorInfo.constructFromJavaArray(TensorInfo.java:208)
    at ai.onnxruntime.OnnxTensor.createTensor(OnnxTensor.java:330)
    at ai.onnxruntime.OnnxTensor.createTensor(OnnxTensor.java:314)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an old issue. The example code works with the current version of the onnxruntime API (1.14.0).

```java
...
var myTensor = OnnxTensor.createTensor(env, 10.0f);
System.out.println(myTensor);
```

---

output:

```java
OnnxTensor(info=TensorInfo(javaType=FLOAT,onnxType=ONNX_TENSOR_ELEMENT_DATA_TYPE_FLOAT,shape=[]))
```

Comment: Edit this properly by Ctrl +K (ing the code)